# how to merge two select queries?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I solved that query... but now I have to merge these two queries:

```
(SELECT Zila,
COUNT(AbhidayMaster.OfficeRegId) As AbhidayPaidSansthan,
SUM(AbhidayMaster.TotalEmp) As TotalWorkerPaid
FROM PanjikaranMaster, AbhidayMaster
WHERE PanjikaranMaster.OfficeRegId=AbhidayMaster.OfficeRegId
AND AbhidayMaster.DipositDate Between ('2012-06-22') AND ('2012-09-19') GROUP BY Zila)



Select 
((SELECT count(distinct OfficeRegId) FROM PanjikaranMaster)
 -
(SELECT count(distinct OfficeRegId) FROM AbhidayMaster)) As AbhidayNotPaidSansthan
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT 
   Zila, 
   COUNT(AbhidayMaster.OfficeRegId) As AbhidayPaidSansthan ,
   SUM(AbhidayMaster.TotalEmp) As TotalWorkerPaid
FROM 
   PanjikaranMaster
INNER JOIN
   AbhidayMaster ON PanjikaranMaster.OfficeRegId = AbhidayMaster.OfficeRegId
WHERE
   AbhidayMaster.DipositDate BETWEEN '20120622' AND '20120919'
GROUP BY 
   Zila
```

I changed your JOIN syntax to use the proper ANSI/ISO standard JOINs - an explicit `INNER JOIN` with the JOIN condition right there where it belongs (see [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) to learn why the "old-style" JOIN is a really bad idea and should be avoided).

I also changed your date string literals to be language- and regional settings-safe - the format is `YYYYMMDD` (**no dashes**!)

Comment: @user1673240: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: thanks for your help...... that issue has been solved.. again i am stuck in another query.. please see the above updated query.